# Отсекается высота div'а

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

высота div'а `oth-serv-cont` = 395px, но при добавлении `top: 238px`,  "съедает", как я понял 147px. Почему так происходит и как исправить? Заранее спасибо!

```css
.oth-serv-cont {
  position: relative;
  width: 1110px;
  height: 395px;
  top: 238px;
  margin: auto;
  background-color:red;
}

.block {
  position: absolute;
  width: 350px;
  height: 145px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.idea {
  background-color: #343434;
}

.best {
  left: 380px;
}

.game {
  left: 760px;
}

.design {
  top: 250px;
}

.free {
  left: 380px;
  top: 250px;
}

.bonus {
  left: 760px;
  top: 250px;
}
```

```html
<div class="oth-serv-cont">
  <div class="idea block"></div>
  <div class="best block"></div>
  <div class="game block"></div>
  <div class="design block"></div>
  <div class="free block"></div>
  <div class="bonus block"></div>
</div>
```

[image: На данном скриншоте видно, что черные прямоугольники и белый фон обрезаны, а у <code>.oth-serv-cont</code> еще осталось место]

Comment: Изменил цвета для наглядности, а какого еще ты поведения хотел от абсолютного позиционирования?

Comment: Зачем вам на элементе `oth-serv-cont` свойство `top: 238px`, если вы не понимаете как работает `position`?

Comment: @E_K прочёл документацию, но все еще не доходит как исправить. Не подскажете как?

Comment: @NickGrom, вы смещаете блок относительного его исходного места, скорее всего он скрывается под следующим блоком.
Что бы дать более точный ответ, воспроизведите проблему в примере(добавьте верстку и стили остальных блоков) и ответьте на вопрос выше, зачем вы используете `top: 238px`?

Comment: @E_K,  `other-serv-cont` лежит еще в одном блоке, от начала которого я и отступал. Ошибку нашел. Заключалась она в общем блоке `inner-content`, `height` которого был равен 2000px. Вы натолкнули на решение, Спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Используйте за место top, margin-top